# PHP: Injecting a class not implementing a interface – risky business?

Tags: php, dependency-injection, twig

In a PHP application I want to use the [Twig template engine](http://twig.sensiolabs.org). To keep things modular and flexible, I would like to inject Twig with Dependency Injection.

From their documentation:

> Twig uses a central object called the environment (of class Twig_Environment). Instances of this class are used to store the configuration and extensions, and are used to load templates from the file system or other locations.

And an example that shows a simple way to initialize Twig:

```
$loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem('/path/to/templates');
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader, array(
    'cache' => '/path/to/compilation_cache',
));
```

Since two objects are required, I think I need a factory at some point, that initializes the `Twig_Environment` class for the with a Twig loader.

But how I am supposed to inject the initialized `Twig_Environment` class into another class? Taking a look at the Twig source code, I can see that the `Twig_Environment` class does not implement any interface I could use as a type hint, so injecting seems a bit risky to me.

Is there any solution to this?

All loaders (passed into `Twig_Environment` on instantiation) implement two interfaces: `Twig_LoaderInterface` and `Twig_ExistsLoaderInterface`. Is there a way to somehow use them as a type hint?

Currently I directly use `Twig_Environment` as type hint, but this seems to be a bit strict.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do largely depends on how tightly you want to couple your app with Twig.

If you intend to use Twig, are not planning on using another templating engine at any point, and don't mind tightly coupling with twig, then you can go ahead and hint on `\Twig_Environment`. Twig itself typehints extensively on `\Twig_Environment`.

If you think you might reasonably swap out your template engine for something else, or need to have two completely different engines, then you might instead want to create a wrapper around the Twig Environment and typehint on that wrapper. Symfony does this, with a TwigEngine and PhpEngine, which both implement EngineInterface, and provide wrappers around rendering with twig and rendering with php.

If you create a wrapper, how extensive it needs to be is entirely up to you, but until you actually have a second engine you want to use, it should probably be pretty thin. The simplest possible wrapper would just be something like:

```
interface TemplatingEngineInterface {}
class TwigEnvironmentWrapper extends \Twig_Environment implements TemplatingEngineInterface {}
```